# Нужен ли Nginx при написании бэкенда мобильного приложения?

Tags: nginx, golang, mobile-development, backend, mobile

Планируется писать бэкенд для мобильного приложения на go. Требуется ли поднимать Nginx (любой другой веб-сервер) и в каких случаях?

Comment: Можно и без него, если будете следовать правилам предосторожности.  _Cloudflare_ писали об этом: https://blog.cloudflare.com/exposing-go-on-the-internet/.

Comment: я использую  nginx вместе с go, он очень много умеет из коробки, удобно.